# Overriding a document.body.scrollTop call

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, kotlin, webview

I have an Android app that needs to use a WebView to load a web app. I cannot change any of the javascript in the web app.  There is a bug where the scrolling does not work in this web app, I suspect it is because it uses document.body.scrollTop instead of document.documentElement.scrollTop.  Is there anyway to change the javascript file locally or override the document.body.scrollTop calls?

Comment: I have no idea bout Android apps, but this may work: `document.body.scrollTop = document.documentElement.scrollTop;` this ofc assumes andriod has a document.body property

Comment: I don't think this would be the correct place to ask something like this, but at least for Firefox on Android there's Greasemonkey. It allowes you to inject local javascript into the website and try to "fix" the issue that way.